# Como rotar (pivotear) los registros de una tabla

Tags: sql-server

Buen día, 
Prové con un pivot normal y no me funciona ya que se deben especificar los nombres de las columnas pero en este caso no se si sea cuestión de pivot.

¿Cómo se pueden obtener estos resultados? ¿es posible?

```
DECLARE @TEMP_INC TABLE (
        INC_ID INT,
        OBJ_ID INT,
        INC_DESCRIPCION VARCHAR(255),
        INC_TIPOOBJ INT,
        INC_FC DATE,
        INC_FM DATE,
        INA_ID INT
        )

INSERT INTO @TEMP_INC (INC_ID, OBJ_ID, INC_DESCRIPCION, INC_TIPOOBJ, INC_FC, INC_FM, INA_ID) 
VALUES
(1439166,   620310, '* descripcion tipo 123',   7,  '2015-07-04 17:07:36.000',  '2015-07-04 17:07:36.000', 8),
(1439167,   620310, '* descripcion tipo 124',   7,  '2015-07-04 17:07:36.000',  '2015-07-04 17:07:36.000', 8),
(1439168,   620311, '* descripcion tipo 125',   7,  '2015-07-04 17:07:37.000',  '2015-07-04 17:07:37.000', 12),
(1439169,   620311, '* descripcion tipo 126',   7,  '2015-07-04 17:07:37.000',  '2015-07-04 17:07:37.000', 15),
(1439170,   620312, '* descripcion tipo 127',   7,  '2015-07-04 17:07:37.000',  '2015-07-04 17:07:37.000', 20),
(1439171,   620312, '* descripcion tipo 128',   7,  '2015-07-04 17:07:37.000',  '2015-07-04 17:07:37.000', 22),
(1439172,   620313, '* descripcion tipo 129',   7,  '2015-07-04 17:07:38.000',  '2015-07-04 17:07:38.000', 27),
(1439173,   620313, '* descripcion tipo 132',   7,  '2015-07-04 17:07:38.000',  '2015-07-04 17:07:38.000', 26),
(1439174,   620314, '* descripcion tipo 133',   7,  '2015-07-04 17:07:39.000',  '2015-07-04 17:07:39.000', 26),
(1439175,   620314, '* descripcion tipo 134',   7,  '2015-07-04 17:07:39.000',  '2015-07-04 17:07:39.000', 24)

SELECT 
        INC_ID,
        OBJ_ID,
        INC_DESCRIPCION,
        INC_TIPOOBJ,
        INC_FC,
        INC_FM,
        INA_ID
FROM @TEMP_INC
```

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fivIJ.png): Resultado Normal

[image: Resultado Normal]

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BXeB5.png): Resultado esperado

[image: Resultado esperado]

Comment: Según tu ejemplo, lo que quieres es traer todo el resultado y luego separarlo en 2 bloques, directamente con un query, es así?

Comment: Si señor, exactamente, pero pues pueden haber mas de dos bloques, pueden ser hasta 5, 8 o hasta 18 o mas.

Comment: La solución es sin duda el uso de `PIVOT`, podrías eventualmente evitar el definir los nombres de las columnas mediante una consulta dinámica, pero es bastante complejo. Por otro lado, de forma horizontal siempre tendrás un límite de columnas (creo que eran 2000 ¿?). Cuantos niveles de transposición estimas? o es indeterminado?

Comment: Es indeterminado, pero hasta el momento lo máximo ha llegado a 18 niveles, pueden crecer sin duda aunque esta base lleva mas de 2 años y pues no ha pasado de 18 niveles x unas 7 columnas cada una, serían 126 columnas si no me equivoco.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La siguiente es una solución basada en una consulta dinámica adaptada a los propios datos, se puede usar `PIVOT` pero seguimos teniendo el problema de no querer "escribir" todos los niveles de transposición, por lo que siempre deberemos pasar por una consulta dinámica. Este tipo de consultas tiene sus problemas asociados, falta de optimización del motor, problemas de seguridad, y un limite en el tamaño de la sentencia en `NVARCHAR(MAX)`, para lo que buscas seguramente te sirva.

En primer lugar debemos transformar tu tabla tipo variable a una tabla física aunque sea temporal para que la ejecución mediante `sp_executesql` pueda "ver" la tabla. Agregué además un tercer nivel solo para probar.

```
SET NOCOUNT ON

CREATE TABLE #TEMP_INC (
        INC_ID INT,
        OBJ_ID INT,
        INC_DESCRIPCION VARCHAR(255),
        INC_TIPOOBJ INT,
        INC_FC DATE,
        INC_FM DATE,
        INA_ID INT,
    NUM INT
        )

INSERT INTO #TEMP_INC (INC_ID, OBJ_ID, INC_DESCRIPCION, INC_TIPOOBJ, INC_FC, INC_FM, INA_ID) 
VALUES
(1439166,   620310, '* descripcion tipo 123',   7,  '2015-07-04 17:07:36.000',  '2015-07-04 17:07:36.000', 8),
(1439167,   620310, '* descripcion tipo 124',   7,  '2015-07-04 17:07:36.000',  '2015-07-04 17:07:36.000', 8),
(1439168,   620311, '* descripcion tipo 125',   7,  '2015-07-04 17:07:37.000',  '2015-07-04 17:07:37.000', 12),
(1439169,   620311, '* descripcion tipo 126',   7,  '2015-07-04 17:07:37.000',  '2015-07-04 17:07:37.000', 15),
(1439170,   620312, '* descripcion tipo 127',   7,  '2015-07-04 17:07:37.000',  '2015-07-04 17:07:37.000', 20),
(1439171,   620312, '* descripcion tipo 128',   7,  '2015-07-04 17:07:37.000',  '2015-07-04 17:07:37.000', 22),
(1439172,   620313, '* descripcion tipo 129',   7,  '2015-07-04 17:07:38.000',  '2015-07-04 17:07:38.000', 27),
(1439173,   620313, '* descripcion tipo 132',   7,  '2015-07-04 17:07:38.000',  '2015-07-04 17:07:38.000', 26),
(1439174,   620314, '* descripcion tipo 133',   7,  '2015-07-04 17:07:39.000',  '2015-07-04 17:07:39.000', 26),
(1439175,   620314, '* descripcion tipo 134',   7,  '2015-07-04 17:07:39.000',  '2015-07-04 17:07:39.000', 24),
(1439176,   620314, '* descripcion tipo 135',   7,  '2015-07-04 17:07:39.000',  '2015-07-04 17:07:40.000', 25)

-- Obtengo el máximo nivel de apertura    
DECLARE @MaxLevels  INT

SELECT  @MaxLevels = MAX(Cantidad)
    FROM (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT INC_ID) AS 'Cantidad'
            FROM    #TEMP_INC
                GROUP BY OBJ_ID
    ) c


UPDATE  #TEMP_INC
    SET NUM = N.NUM
    FROM #TEMP_INC T
    INNER JOIN (SELECT INC_ID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY OBJ_ID ORDER BY OBJ_ID, INC_ID) AS NUM
            FROM #TEMP_INC
        ) N
        ON N.INC_ID = T.INC_ID

DECLARE @SQL    NVARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT  @SQL    = 'SELECT' + CHAR(13)

SELECT  @SQL    = @SQL +'' + 
            '       MAX(CASE WHEN NUM = ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,N.NUM) + ' THEN INC_ID ELSE NULL END) AS ''INC_ID' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,N.NUM) + ''', ' + CHAR(13) +
            '       MAX(CASE WHEN NUM = ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,N.NUM) + ' THEN OBJ_ID ELSE NULL END) AS ''OBJ_ID' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,N.NUM) + ''', ' + CHAR(13) +
            '       MAX(CASE WHEN NUM = ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,N.NUM) + ' THEN INC_DESCRIPCION ELSE NULL END) AS ''INC_DESCRIPCION' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,N.NUM) + ''', ' + CHAR(13) +
            '       MAX(CASE WHEN NUM = ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,N.NUM) + ' THEN INC_TIPOOBJ ELSE NULL END) AS ''INC_TIPOOBJ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,N.NUM) + ''', ' + CHAR(13) +
            '       MAX(CASE WHEN NUM = ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,N.NUM) + ' THEN INC_FC ELSE NULL END) AS ''INC_FC' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,N.NUM) + ''', ' + CHAR(13) +
            '       MAX(CASE WHEN NUM = ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,N.NUM) + ' THEN INC_FM ELSE NULL END) AS ''INC_FM' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,N.NUM) + ''', ' + CHAR(13) +
            '       MAX(CASE WHEN NUM = ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,N.NUM) + ' THEN INA_ID ELSE NULL END) AS ''INA_ID' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,N.NUM) + ''', ' + CHAR(13) +
            ''
    FROM ( SELECT   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID) AS NUM
            FROM SYSCOLUMNS
    ) N
    WHERE N.NUM <= @MaxLevels

SELECT  @SQL    = LEFT(@SQL, LEN(@SQL)- 3)

SELECT  @SQL    = @SQL + CHAR(13) +
            '       FROM #TEMP_INC' + CHAR(13) +
            '       GROUP BY OBJ_ID'


-- PRINT    @SQL

SET NOCOUNT OFF
EXECUTE SP_EXECUTESQL @SQL

DROP TABLE #TEMP_INC
```

#### Explicación

1. Obtenemos el máximo nivel de apertura posible, es decir cuantas
   columnas * niveles vamos a "transponer" (`@MaxLevels`)
2. Actualizamos un nuevo campo `NUM` que numera cada nuevo registro de
   `OBJ_ID` y que usaremos luego
3. Generamos el `@SQL` dinamico repitiendo cada campo por `@MaxLevels`,
   usamos una tabla cualquier, en mi caso `syscolumns` que tenga muchos
   registros para generar una secuencia, obviamente la cantidad de
   registros debe ser superior a `@MaxLevels`
4. Terminamos de completar la sentencia y la ejecutamos mediante
   `EXECUTE SP_EXECUTESQL @SQL`

Si tienes curiosidad de como es la sentencia final, acá un ejemplo

```
SELECT
       MAX(CASE WHEN NUM = 1 THEN INC_ID ELSE NULL END) AS 'INC_ID1', 
       MAX(CASE WHEN NUM = 1 THEN OBJ_ID ELSE NULL END) AS 'OBJ_ID1', 
       MAX(CASE WHEN NUM = 1 THEN INC_DESCRIPCION ELSE NULL END) AS 'INC_DESCRIPCION1', 
       MAX(CASE WHEN NUM = 1 THEN INC_TIPOOBJ ELSE NULL END) AS 'INC_TIPOOBJ1', 
       MAX(CASE WHEN NUM = 1 THEN INC_FC ELSE NULL END) AS 'INC_FC1', 
       MAX(CASE WHEN NUM = 1 THEN INC_FM ELSE NULL END) AS 'INC_FM1', 
       MAX(CASE WHEN NUM = 1 THEN INA_ID ELSE NULL END) AS 'INA_ID1', 
       MAX(CASE WHEN NUM = 2 THEN INC_ID ELSE NULL END) AS 'INC_ID2', 
       MAX(CASE WHEN NUM = 2 THEN OBJ_ID ELSE NULL END) AS 'OBJ_ID2', 
       MAX(CASE WHEN NUM = 2 THEN INC_DESCRIPCION ELSE NULL END) AS 'INC_DESCRIPCION2', 
       MAX(CASE WHEN NUM = 2 THEN INC_TIPOOBJ ELSE NULL END) AS 'INC_TIPOOBJ2', 
       MAX(CASE WHEN NUM = 2 THEN INC_FC ELSE NULL END) AS 'INC_FC2', 
       MAX(CASE WHEN NUM = 2 THEN INC_FM ELSE NULL END) AS 'INC_FM2', 
       MAX(CASE WHEN NUM = 2 THEN INA_ID ELSE NULL END) AS 'INA_ID2', 
       MAX(CASE WHEN NUM = 3 THEN INC_ID ELSE NULL END) AS 'INC_ID3', 
       MAX(CASE WHEN NUM = 3 THEN OBJ_ID ELSE NULL END) AS 'OBJ_ID3', 
       MAX(CASE WHEN NUM = 3 THEN INC_DESCRIPCION ELSE NULL END) AS 'INC_DESCRIPCION3', 
       MAX(CASE WHEN NUM = 3 THEN INC_TIPOOBJ ELSE NULL END) AS 'INC_TIPOOBJ3', 
       MAX(CASE WHEN NUM = 3 THEN INC_FC ELSE NULL END) AS 'INC_FC3', 
       MAX(CASE WHEN NUM = 3 THEN INC_FM ELSE NULL END) AS 'INC_FM3', 
       MAX(CASE WHEN NUM = 3 THEN INA_ID ELSE NULL END) AS 'INA_ID3'
       FROM #TEMP_INC
       GROUP BY OBJ_ID
```

Comment: Wow @Patricio Moracho, esto debe estudiarse con calma, voy a analizar lo que me envías y le cuento en un rato como me fue, Muchas gracias por la explicación es lo que más me interesa, saber como y no simplemente hacerlo!

Comment: Casi casi compadre, en la tabla de pruebas funciona, pero en la real obtengo error de `The number of elements in the select list exceeds the maximum allowed number of 4096 elements.`

Comment: Revisa por las dudas el valor calculado para `@MaxLevels` por el error indicaría que tienes más de 585 niveles y no 18.

Comment: Si calculé mal, al parecer existen muchos mas que 4096 según el error. :(

Comment: En realidad son 4096 / 7 campos es decir más de 585 "niveles", los niveles los calculo en función de los `DISTINCT INC_ID` por cada `OBJ_ID`, fijate si efectivamente es es el criterio. Por otro lado prueba quitar algunos campos que no necesites. No hay muchas posibilidades más.

Answer (score 1):

Según la imagen del resultado esperado y los registros, podrías considerar el orden de la columna `INC_ID` e igual el valor de la columna `OBJ_ID` del anterior con el actual registro .

Por ejemplo:

```
;WITH TEMP
AS (SELECT LAG(INC_ID) OVER (ORDER BY INC_ID) [INC_ID_1]
       ,INC_ID [INC_ID_2]
    FROM @TEMP_INC
   )
SELECT T1.*
   ,T2.*
FROM TEMP T
    INNER JOIN @TEMP_INC T1
        ON T1.INC_ID = T.INC_ID_1
    INNER JOIN @TEMP_INC T2
        ON T2.INC_ID = T.INC_ID_2
WHERE T1.OBJ_ID = T2.OBJ_ID
```

Aprovecho la función [LAG](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql) que está disponible a partir de SQL Server 2012; para otras versiones sería jugando con la secuencia de cada registro.

Comment: Davlio, primero que todo compadre muchas gracias por su tiempo y respuesta, esto funciona también con mas de 2 `@TEMP`? es decir puede que el mismo `OBJ_ID` exista mas de 2 veces incluso hasta 18 veces.

Comment: @Vulpex mi respuesta solo está considerando 2 columnas, leyendo tu comentario indicas que puede sobrepasar en productivo los *4,096* columnas por instrucción `SELECT`. Sería bueno que leyeras [Especificaciones de capacidad máxima para SQL Server](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/sql-server/maximum-capacity-specifications-for-sql-server)

Comment: Si lo se, según eso pues no es posible realizar tal consulta, cierto?