# MySQL pivot con 3 tablas no funciona bien

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, select, pivot

Estoy tratando de ejecutar una sentencia select que al ejecutarla en phpmyadmin, consulte estas tres tablas:

- Tabla 1: personas (Lista de personas)
- Tabla 2: tesoreria (Detalles que paga cada persona)
- Tabla 3: detalle_tesoreria (Tabla de enlace para las das anteriores)

Y se genere una tabla/matriz que contenga la siguiente estructura:

> ```
> nomb-apell   detalle1         detalle2         detalle3 
> persona1     abono            abono            abono
> persona2     abono            abono            abono
> persona3     abono            abono            abono
> ```

Codigo de las tablas:

```
CREATE TABLE personas (
Id INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL UNIQUE AUTO_INCREMENT,
Nombres VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
Apellidos VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT PK_Persona PRIMARY KEY(Id));

CREATE TABLE tesoreria (
Id INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL UNIQUE AUTO_INCREMENT,
Detalle VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
Valor BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT PK_Tesoreria PRIMARY KEY(Id));

CREATE TABLE detalle_tesoreria (
Id_persona INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
Id_tesoreria INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
Abono INTEGER NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT PK_DetalleTesoreria PRIMARY KEY(Id_persona, Id_tesoreria));

ALTER TABLE detalle_tesoreria ADD CONSTRAINT FK_DetalleTesoreria_Persona FOREIGN KEY(Id_persona) REFERENCES personas(Id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE RESTRICT;
ALTER TABLE detalle_tesoreria ADD CONSTRAINT FK_DetalleTesoreria_Tesoreria FOREIGN KEY(Id_tesoreria) REFERENCES tesoreria(Id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE RESTRICT;
```

Codigo de los registros:

```
INSERT INTO personas VALUES (DEFAULT, 'Camila Antonia', 'Perez Ceron');
INSERT INTO personas VALUES (DEFAULT, 'Antonia', 'Narvaes Samboni');
INSERT INTO personas VALUES (DEFAULT, 'Camila', 'Rodriguez Pelaes');
INSERT INTO personas VALUES (DEFAULT, 'Laura Natalia', 'Rodriguez Ramirez');

INSERT INTO tesoreria VALUES (DEFAULT, 'Detalle 1', 2200);
INSERT INTO tesoreria VALUES (DEFAULT, 'Detalle 2', 3300);
INSERT INTO tesoreria VALUES (DEFAULT, 'Detalle 3', 4400);

INSERT INTO detalle_tesoreria VALUES (1, 1, 1100);
INSERT INTO detalle_tesoreria VALUES (1, 3, 1000);
INSERT INTO detalle_tesoreria VALUES (2, 2, 2000);
```

Para realizar la consulta en forma de que se genere una matriz/tabla horizontal ejecuto esta consulta:

```
select p.Nombres, p.Apellidos,
(case when t.Id = '1' THEN dt.Abono END) Detalle1,
(case when t.Id = '2' THEN dt.Abono END) Detalle2,
(case when t.Id = '3' THEN dt.Abono END) Detalle3
from personas p
left join detalle_tesoreria dt
on p.Id = dt.Id_persona
left join tesoreria t
on dt.Id_tesoreria = t.Id
group by p.Id;
```

Pero no me muestra todos los abonos que han hecho las personas dentro de la matriz, en este caso de tres abonos, me muestra solo dos abonos.

Estoy utilizando XAMPP 7.3.2 y MariaDB 10.1.38 y pueden probar el codigo de arriba [aqui](https://dbfiddle.uk) o [aqui](https://sqlfiddle.com)

PSDT: Estuve mirando [esta pregunta en stackoverflow en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32172226/mysql-pivot-with-3-tables), pero me arroja un error.

PSDT: La sentencia que genera la matriz la tome y modifique para mi caso en la respuesta que encontre en [esta otra pregunta en stackoverflow en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12004603/mysql-pivot-row-into-dynamic-number-of-columns/12005676#12005676) que me funciona perfectamente cuando se utiliza el count, pero en mi caso necesito es un valor y no contar.

Comment: ¿cuál es la lógica que sigues para obtener la leyenda abono?, pues yo veo que es un `INTEGER` que almacena valores distintos

Comment: Si, es de tipo integer y pues almacena las diferentes cantidades que la persona abone.
Basicamente para obtener el abono comparo que el id del detalle de tesoreria debe ser el mismo que se encuentre en la tabla detalle_tesoreria y que sea de la persona correspondiente, para poder mostrar el abono en la celda respectiva.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si te entendí bien, esto creo que es lo que buscas:

```
select p.Id,
       p.Nombres,
       p.Apellidos,
       SUM(CASE WHEN dt.Id_Tesoreria = 1 THEN Abono ELSE 0 END) AS 'Detalle1',
       SUM(CASE WHEN dt.Id_Tesoreria = 2 THEN Abono ELSE 0 END) AS 'Detalle2',
       SUM(CASE WHEN dt.Id_Tesoreria = 3 THEN Abono ELSE 0 END) AS 'Detalle3'
       from personas p
       left join detalle_tesoreria dt
            on p.Id = dt.Id_persona
       left join tesoreria t
            on dt.Id_tesoreria = t.Id
       GROUP BY p.Id,
                p.Nombres,
                p.Apellidos
;
```

Salida:

```
| Id |        Nombres |         Apellidos | Detalle1 | Detalle2 | Detalle3 |
|----|----------------|-------------------|----------|----------|----------|
|  1 | Camila Antonia |       Perez Ceron |     1100 |        0 |     1000 |
|  2 |        Antonia |   Narvaes Samboni |        0 |     2000 |        0 |
|  3 |         Camila |  Rodriguez Pelaes |        0 |        0 |        0 |
|  4 |  Laura Natalia | Rodriguez Ramirez |        0 |        0 |        0 |
```

Detalle:

- Se trata de agrupar por persona y hacer una suma condicional en función del detalle
- Obviamente esta solución está limitada a 3 únicos detalles.
- Las columnas que estén en el `select` pero no en una función de agregación (por ej. el `SUM()`) son las mismas por las que debemos agrupar mediante el `group by`
- Puedes verificar este [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c56c06/8)

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, me ha funcionado muy bien. Ahora tengo esta duda, tesorería tiene 3 registros y si agrego otro, también tendría que agregar otro case en la consulta así sucesivamente ¿es posible que automáticamente se generen las columnas en la matriz, dependiendo de si agregan mas registros a la tabla tesorería?

Comment: Efectivamente es así, nuevo detalle, hay que definir nueva columna a la consulta. ¿Se puede hacer automáticamente? si, pero es complejo de resolver desde el código SQL y es una mecánica totalmente distinta, tendrías que crear dinámicamente  un consulta en función de la cantidad de detalles que tengas y luego ejecutarla. Además, cada base de datos, tiene un limite de columnas, es decir no puedes crecer indefinidamente. Ademas hay cuestiones de legibilidad de la información, imagina una consulta de 100 columnas nada más.

Comment: Entiendo la complejidad, mi idea es hacerlo ya que con ello podre exportar el reporte completo, y encontré una buena respuesta que hiciste en https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/172281/poner-cada-fila-obtenida-en-columnas-independientes-mysql pero al tratar de acomodarla no me reconoce el nr dentro del case (no se como modificarla correctamente). ¿Fusionando la respuesta que diste (adaptada a este caso) pueda resolver la duda que te plantee?.

Comment: La respuesta que mencionas es conceptualmente la misma solución que esta. Necesitas otra forma de resolverlo, para SQL Server está esta pregunta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/90695/como-rotar-pivotear-los-registros-de-una-tabla/90738#90738, que es la idea que te mencioné, generar una consulta dinámica y luego ejecutar la misma. Te sugiero que hagas una nueva pregunta, con los datos de tu pregunta y la consulta de mi respuesta y menciona que lo que buscas es algo parecido pero para un número mayor, y variable de columnas. No tengo experiencia con sentencias dinámicas en mysql.