# MySQL/MariaDB pivot dinamico con 3 tablas

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, select, mariadb, pivot

Actualmente he encontrado la forma de generar una tabla/matriz con 3 tablas que tiene la siguiente estructura:

> ```
> nomb-apell   detalle1         detalle2         detalle3 
> persona1     abono            abono            abono
> persona2     abono            abono            abono
> persona3     abono            abono            abono
> ```

Ejecutando la siguiente sentencia SQL:

```
select p.Id,
p.Nombres,
p.Apellidos,
SUM(CASE WHEN dt.Id_Tesoreria = 1 THEN Abono ELSE 0 END) AS 'Detalle1',
SUM(CASE WHEN dt.Id_Tesoreria = 2 THEN Abono ELSE 0 END) AS 'Detalle2',
SUM(CASE WHEN dt.Id_Tesoreria = 3 THEN Abono ELSE 0 END) AS 'Detalle3'
from personas p
left join detalle_tesoreria dt
 on p.Id = dt.Id_persona
left join tesoreria t
 on dt.Id_tesoreria = t.Id
GROUP BY p.Id,
 p.Nombres,
 p.Apellidos
;
```

Pero estoy agregando una nueva columna a una tabla que la sentencia SQL toma como nombres de las columnas (detalle#) y queda de la siguiente manera:

> ```
> id        detalle             valor 
> 1         detalle1            valor1
> 2         detalle2            valor2
> 3         detalle3            valor3
> 4         detalle4            valor4
> ```

El problema es que a la sentencia SQL tambien deberia agregarle una linea con la estructura de los SUM (para la nueva columna); pero esto deberia hacerse de forma automática, es decir, a medida que se agregue un nuevo registro, la sentencia SQL deberia tomar cada nuevo registro y posicionarlo como una columna, porque resulta engorroso un doble trabajo.

Para ejecutar la anterior sentencia SQL [utiliza el codigo de las tablas y sus respectivos registros proporcionados en esta otra pregunta en StackOverflow en español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/271941/mysql-pivot-con-3-tablas-no-funciona-bien)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actualmente pude crear una sentencia SQL que soluciona el problema, al leer diferentes fuentes que citare al final de esta respuesta.

La unica forma de crear una sentencia SQL dinámica (dynamic SQL) en MySQL/MariaDB es a través de Sentencias Preparadas (Prepared Statements) obteniendo:

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
CONCAT(
  'MAX(CASE WHEN dt.Id_tesoreria = ''',
  dt.Id_tesoreria,
  ''' THEN Abono END) AS `',
  t.Detalle, '`'
)
) INTO @sql
from detalle_tesoreria dt
        left join tesoreria t
        on dt.Id_tesoreria = t.Id;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT p.Id,
   p.Nombres,
   p.Apellidos, ', @sql, ' 
              from personas p
   left join detalle_tesoreria dt
        on p.Id = dt.Id_persona
   left join tesoreria t
        on dt.Id_tesoreria = t.Id
   GROUP BY p.Id,
            p.Nombres,
            p.Apellidos');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Se esta creando una consulta automatica inicial que obtiene todos los registros de la tabla para las columnas de la matriz y luego lo concatena con la ultima consulta que se encarga de generar las filas de la matriz.

- Fuente 1: [Documentación en la página oficial de MariaDB sobre Prepare Statement](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/prepare-statement/)
- Fuente 2: [Sintaxis y explicación de los casos donde se aplican los Prepare Statement y sus limitaciones](https://falseisnotnull.wordpress.com/2017/04/10/prepared-statements-in-mariadb-10-2/)
- Fuente 3: [Respuesta proporcionada en una pregunta similar en StackOverflow en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32172226/mysql-pivot-with-3-tables)

Comment: Buena respuesta! te he dado un +1, invito a la comunidad a hacer lo mismo. Solo un comentario adicional, el crecimiento "horizontal" en cuanto a columnas tiene un límite, en el caso de mysql es de 4096 columnas.