# Crear tabla con pivot dinámico que contenga una fila y una columna adicional de total

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, select, mariadb, pivot

Con la siguiente sentencia sql se generan dinamicamente las columnas de una pivot table:

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
CONCAT(
'MAX(CASE WHEN dt.Id_tesoreria = ''',
 dt.Id_tesoreria,
''' THEN Abono END) AS `',
t.Detalle, '`'
)
) INTO @sql
from detalle_tesoreria dt
    left join tesoreria t
    on dt.Id_tesoreria = t.Id;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT p.Id,
p.Nombres,
p.Apellidos, ', @sql, ' 
          from personas p
left join detalle_tesoreria dt
    on p.Id = dt.Id_persona
left join tesoreria t
    on dt.Id_tesoreria = t.Id
GROUP BY p.Id,
        p.Nombres,
        p.Apellidos');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Sentencia SQL tomada de la respuesta brindada en [esta otra pregunta en StackOverflow en español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/271941/mysql-pivot-con-3-tablas-no-funciona-bien)

El resultado es la siguiente matriz:

> ```
> nomb-apell   detalle1         detalle2         detalle3 
> persona1     abono            abono            abono
> persona2     abono            abono            abono
> persona3     abono            abono            abono
> ```

Ahora lo que busco es modificar la matriz para que tenga la siguiente estructura:

> ```
> nomb-apell   detalle1         detalle2         detalle3         total
> persona1     abono            abono            abono            sum(persona1)
> persona2     abono            abono            abono            sum(persona2)
> persona3     abono            abono            abono            sum(persona3)
> total     sum(detalle1)    sum(detalle2)    sum(detalle3)    sum(sum(detalleN),sum(personaN))
> ```

Para ejecutar la anterior sentencia SQL por favor [utiliza el código de las tablas y sus respectivos registros proporcionados en esta otra pregunta en StackOverflow en español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/274448/mysql-mariadb-pivot-dinamico-con-3-tablas)

He investigado el uso de *with rollup*, pero no funciona cuando se utiliza group_concat segun un [bug reportado aquí](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=54476)

Mi pregunta es como reestructurar la sentencia SQL anterior para que genere la matriz con los totales respectivos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actualmente solo es posible crear la columna de totales y la sentencia queda de la siguiente manera (he usado IFNULL para poner un 0 en caso de que la celda este null):

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
CONCAT(
'IFNULL(MAX(CASE WHEN dt.Id_tesoreria = ''',
dt.Id_tesoreria,
''' THEN Abono END), 0) AS `',
t.Detalle, '`'
)
) INTO @sql
from detalle_tesoreria dt
    left join tesoreria t
    on dt.Id_tesoreria = t.Id;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT p.Id,
p.Nombres,
p.Apellidos, ', @sql, ' , IFNULL(SUM(dt.Abono), 0) AS Total 
          from personas p
left join detalle_tesoreria dt
    on p.Id = dt.Id_persona
left join tesoreria t
    on dt.Id_tesoreria = t.Id
GROUP BY p.Id,
        p.Nombres,
        p.Apellidos');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Generando el siguiente resultado:

> ```
> nomb-apell   detalle1         detalle2         detalle3         total
> persona1     abono            abono            abono            sum(persona1)
> persona2     abono            abono            abono            sum(persona2)
> persona3     abono            abono            abono            sum(persona3)
> ```

De acuerdo al bug, mencionado en la pregunta, actualmente no encontre una forma de generar la fila para los totales cuando se generan columnas a través de un pivot dinámico.

Pero, si es posible crear la fila de totales cuando hacemos un pivot estático, haciendo uso de *WITH ROLLUP*.