# Tabla pivot mysql o programación php para crear tabla con columna según rango de fechas y filas

Tags: php, mysqli, tablas

En MySQL tengo 3 tablas

```
Tabla usuario
Rut
Seudonimo

Tabla Estado
Id_Estado
EstadoP

Tabla Asistencia
Id_Asis
Rut
Id_Estado
Fecha
```

intento realizar una tabla Pivot pero las fecha son seleccionadas por un rango de fecha.

Se que realizando una tabla normal obtengo:

```
Rut | Nombre | Estado   | Fecha
----+--------+----------+------
A   | FRAN   | Activo   | 1
B   | lUIS   | ausente  | 1
C   | jORGE  | Vacacion | 1
A   | FRAN   | Activo   | 2
B   | lUIS   | Activo   | 2
C   | jORGE  | Vacacion | 2
```

Y lo que necesito conseguir es:

```
Rut | Nombre | 1        | 2
----+--------+----------+-------
A   | FRAN   | Activo   | Activo
B   | LUIS   | Ausente  | Activo
C   | JORGE  | Vacacion | Activo
```

Espero alguien me pueda ayudar, comparto la tabla Pivot, pero esta al revés, me salen los estados arriba y las fechas dentro, aparte que no se como hacer para que se pueda seleccionar el rango de fechas:

```
    SET @sql = NULL;
 SELECT
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
CONCAT(
'MAX(CASE WHEN Asistencia.Id_Estado = ''',
 Asistencia.Id_Estado,
''' THEN Asistencia.Fecha END) AS `',
estado_usuario.EstadoP, '`'
)
 ) INTO @sql
from Asistencia
    left join estado_usuario
    on Asistencia.Id_Estado = estado_usuario.Id_Estado;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT usuario.Rut,
usuario.Seudonimo, ', @sql, ' 
          from Asistencia
left join usuario
    on asistencia.Rut = usuario.Rut
    left join estado_usuario
    on usuario.Id_Estado = estado_usuario.Id_Estado
GROUP BY usuario.Rut,
usuario.Seudonimo');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

otra opcion que intente fue realizarlo por php, pero consigo lo que necesito si es que defino un rut, pero necesito la tabla con todos los rut, quizas con un for o foreach.

```
$Rut=$_POST['Rut'];
$Fecha1=$_POST['Fecha1'];
$Fecha2=$_POST['Fecha2'];

$sqli="SELECT  Asistencia.Rut, usuario.Seudonimo, Asistencia.Fecha, 
estado_usuario.EstadoP
FROM Asistencia
LEFT JOIN estado_usuario ON Asistencia.Id_Estado    
 =estado_usuario.Id_Estado
LEFT JOIN  usuario       ON Asistencia.Rut           = usuario.Rut
WHERE Asistencia.Rut='$Rut'  AND Asistencia.Fecha BETWEEN '$Fecha1' 
AND 
'$Fecha2' ";

 echo '<table border=1>';
  echo '<tr><th>Rut</th><th>Nombre</th>';

$fecha = array();
$estado = array();
while ($fila = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
    $fecha[] = $fila['Fecha'];
    $estado[] = $fila['EstadoP'];
    $Rut = $fila['Rut'];
    $Nombre = $fila['Seudonimo'];
}
    foreach($fecha as $fec) {
        echo '<th>' . $fec . '</th>';
    }
    echo '</tr>';
echo '<tr>';

echo '<td>' . $Rut. '</td>';
echo '<td>' . $Nombre.  '</td>';

foreach($estado as $est) {
    echo '<td>' . $est . '</td>';
}

echo '</tr></table>';
```

Comment: Tienes que hacer una tabla pivot, al parecer. Revisa si [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/271941/mysql-pivot-con-3-tablas-no-funciona-bien) y su respuesta te son de utilidad

Comment: en ese caso tiene claro el numero de columnas, pero yo intento que se seleccione un rango de fechas y esas sean la cantidad de columnas, por lo que no las puedo dejar definidas en la consulta.

Comment: Eso no era claro en la pregunta o en el ejemplo. Haz el pivot dinámico con GROUP_CONCAT ([como en esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/284405/crear-tabla-con-pivot-din%c3%a1mico-que-contenga-una-fila-y-una-columna-adicional-de))

Answer (score 0):

La solución que estás buscando es:

```
SELECT * FROM usuario
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT Rut,EstadoP AS '1'
      FROM usuario
      JOIN Asistencia USING(Rut)
      JOIN Estado USING(Id_Estado)
      WHERE Fecha=1
  ) c1 USING(Rut)
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT Rut,EstadoP AS '2'
      FROM usuario
      JOIN Asistencia USING(Rut)
      JOIN Estado USING(Id_Estado)
      WHERE Fecha=2
  ) c2 USING(Rut);
```

A partir del dataset que propones:

```
CREATE TABLE usuario(
  Rut varchar(31),
  Seudonimo varchar(31)
  );
CREATE TABLE Estado(
  Id_Estado int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  EstadoP varchar(31)
  );
CREATE TABLE Asistencia(
  Id_Asis int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  Rut varchar(31),
  Id_Estado int,
  Fecha int
  );
INSERT INTO usuario (Rut, Seudonimo) VALUES
('A','FRAN'),
('B','lUIS'), 
('C','jORGE');
INSERT INTO Estado (EstadoP) VALUES
('Activo'),('ausente'),('Vacacion');
INSERT INTO Asistencia (Rut, Id_Estado, Fecha) VALUES
  ('A',1,1),
  ('B',2,1),
  ('C',3,1),
  ('A',1,2),
  ('B',1,2),
  ('C',3,2);
```

Obtendrás el resultado:

```
+------+-----------+----------+----------+
| Rut  | Seudonimo | 1        | 2        |
+------+-----------+----------+----------+
| A    | FRAN      | Activo   | Activo   |
| B    | lUIS      | ausente  | Activo   |
| C    | jORGE     | Vacacion | Vacacion |
+------+-----------+----------+----------+
```

Que no coincide exactamente con el tuyo, entiendo que por una errata al transcribir los datos. El PHP podría ayudarte a generalizar tu consulta con más fechas, simplemente añadiendo nuevos `JOIN` con las diferentes subconsultas, tal que así:

```
<?php

$conn = new mysqli('localhost','root','','_so');

$rs=$conn->query("
    SELECT DISTINCT Fecha
      FROM Asistencia;
");

$sql="
    SELECT * FROM usuario
";

while($r=$rs->fetch_assoc())
    $sql.="
      LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT Rut,EstadoP AS '".$r['Fecha']."'
          FROM usuario
          JOIN Asistencia USING(Rut)
          JOIN Estado USING(Id_Estado)
          WHERE Fecha='".$r['Fecha']."'
      ) c".$r['Fecha']." USING(Rut)
    ";

$sql.=";";

echo '<pre>'.print_r(
    $conn->query($sql)->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC)
    ,true
).'</pre>';
```

Para obtener:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Rut] => A
            [Seudonimo] => FRAN
            [1] => Activo
            [2] => Activo
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Rut] => B
            [Seudonimo] => lUIS
            [1] => ausente
            [2] => Activo
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [Rut] => C
            [Seudonimo] => jORGE
            [1] => Vacacion
            [2] => Vacacion
        )

)
```

Probando con:

```
INSERT INTO Asistencia (Rut, Id_Estado, Fecha) VALUES
('B',3,3);
```

Tu tabla quedaría así:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Rut] => A
            [Seudonimo] => FRAN
            [1] => Activo
            [2] => Activo
            [3] => 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Rut] => B
            [Seudonimo] => lUIS
            [1] => ausente
            [2] => Activo
            [3] => Vacacion
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [Rut] => C
            [Seudonimo] => jORGE
            [1] => Vacacion
            [2] => Vacacion
            [3] => 
        )

)
```

Espero que te haya resultado útil. Déjame cualquier duda en los comentarios.

Comment: gracias por responder, pero lamentablemente aun no me resulta, en php me sale error de syntax sql, en mysql lo probe, claro da si se entregan las fechas, pero no por rango de fecha

Comment: No entiendo tu comentario, ¿puedes explicarme tu duda y decirme en qué línea obtienes el error de sintaxis?

Comment: primero quisiera saber si la tabla usuario tuviera mas informacion de las personas, como se podria realizar el mysql?, y en php me aparece que hay un error en la programacion de mysql, me corre bien en mysql el programa pero php no lo acepta, creo que por utilizar los USING, pero no estoy segura

Comment: El número de campos o registros adicionales de una tabla no debería afectar ni al PHP ni al SQL. El PHP está probado y funciona, tal vez pueda fallarte por la versión de PHP en la que intentes ejectuar el script. ¿Podrías mostrar los mensajes de error que estás recibiendo?

Comment: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-03-01 USING(Rut) LEFT JOIN ( SELECT Rut,EstadoP AS '2023-' at line 9

Comment: Tal vez el problema esté en ese `-03-01` y el `2023-`, ¿cómo has escrito exactamente tu consulta?